# Filtering a Collection Select Based On The Selection Of Other

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a collection of State and another collection of cities. So in my application I want to filter the result of cities according to the selection of the state. 


Code in the models:

```
class State < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cities
end

class City < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :state
end
```

Code in the View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :state, "State:", class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <%= f.collection_select :state_id, @cities, :id, :name, {} , class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :city_id, "City:",class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
     <%= f.collection_select :city_id, @states, :id, :name, {} , class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**There is a way that when a state is selected the cities are updated for those that belongs to the selected state?**

Comment: Yes, but updating select when the user clicks requires the use of ajax. This is the topic for an entire blog post - not a stackoverflow answer. Its also a very common scenario so you should find plenty of tutorials.

Comment: Max, thanks for your answer. I was thinking that it was simple. Do you have any tutorial to recommend me?